# Distribute buttons in div evenly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh6wg9f4/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="mainBox" class="textBox">
    <div id="mainMenuBar">
      <button class="jqueryUIButton">New Diagnosis</button>
      <button class="jqueryUIButton">My Diagnosises</button>
      <button class="jqueryUIButton">My Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mainMenuBar {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #30273a, #8d78a5);
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    resize: none;
    border:1px solid #30273a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #8d78a5;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px; // former 250px
    padding: 0;
    width: 750px;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$( ".jqueryUIButton" ).button();
```

Now the three buttons are in the horizontal center of the DIV-Box. But I want them evenly distributed over the whole width. How can I do that?

Would love any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [the flexbox model](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
```

You can also use `space-between`, and play with margins and padding for a fine-tuned look.

[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqtgfqzh/)

Comment: Just a warning: it's not available on old versions of IE. You must check if it's a problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. But if its just old IE versions, this shouldn't be a problem. :-)

Comment: @progNewbie Check caniuse.com.

Answer (score 3):

That's a typical application for flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/aj88xck2/

Just add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-around;` (or space-between) to the container.

Comment: How is this different from what Denys posted?

Comment: @PraveenKumar obviously I wrote a little slower, so the other answer was displayed first.

Comment: 4 mins difference? :P

Comment: when I started writing my answer, there was no answer yet, so it seems that was four minutes, yes.

Comment: Okay, I believe you. No worries. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**FlexBox** to the Rescue:

```css
#mainMenuBar {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #30273a, #8d78a5);
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  resize: none;
  border:1px solid #30273a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #8d78a5;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px; // former 250px
  padding: 0;
  width: 750px;
  max-width: 80%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="mainBox" class="textBox">
    <div id="mainMenuBar">
      <button class="jqueryUIButton">New Diagnosis</button>
      <button class="jqueryUIButton">My Diagnosises</button>
      <button class="jqueryUIButton">My Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

`<button class="jqueryUIButton" style="height:20px; width:145px">New Diagnosis</button>`

Works 100%

```
** The length of the bar is 440px, divided by 3 you get 145px; **
```

Comment: Also, 146 is closer to reality.